# run javascript every 24 hours

Tags: 6, cron

I want to run a piece of javascript every 24 hours for each specific user? This is to clear HTML5 local storage, how would I run this script every 24 hours for each user when they are logged in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way would be to to store an additional value in local storage that is the last time you cleared it.

Each page view, you simply check that value and if the last time was > 24 hours ago, you clear the local storage and set the last clear time to now.

```
(function () {

  var lastclear = localStorage.getItem('lastclear'),
      time_now  = (new Date()).getTime();

  // .getTime() returns milliseconds so 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 24 days
  if ((time_now - lastclear) > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) {

    localStorage.clear();

    localStorage.setItem('lastclear', time_now);
  }

})();
```

Put this in a JS file that is added only when the current user is logged in.

Here is an example using a module named 'sample':

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function sample_init() {
  global $user;

  // User with uid 0 is anonymous/logged out, any uid greater is logged in.
  if ($user->uid > 0) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'sample') . '/js/sample.js');
  }
}
```

Comment: this is cool but I want to clear it at midnight of each day.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to perform a periodic execution of a javascript code is to use **setTimeout(functionname() , time in millisecond)** function. Write a function say func() and write the javascript code you want to run in the function and at last use setTimeout() function..
e.g.

```
function func() {

.....
........
line of code....
......
.....

setTimeout(function(){
  func(arguments if any);
},24*60*60*60);
}
```

For customizing this for each user you may use php code to check for user authenticity.Hope This helps..

Comment: SetTimeout is for short timeouts, not for this use case. This script stops running when the user closes the browser (tab), so when the user comes back after 24 (or more) hours, the timeout starts over again.